# How can I set custom options on an order item in Magento programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am programmatically creating orders from quotes and want to pass the custom options of the products to the order. For that I am trying to set the custom options on the orderItem that I am creating. I am fetching the custom options array successfully using $options = $itemValue->getOptions()  , but I am unable to set the options on the order item using any of the functions like setCustomOptions(), setOptions(), setProductOptions(), setItemOptions() etc. Am I missing anything here?

```
foreach ($itemsData as $itemIds => $itemValue) {
        $products[$itemValue->getProductId()] = array('qty' => $itemValue->getQty());
        $rowTotal = $itemValue->getPrice() * $itemValue->getQty();        
        $options = $itemValue->getOptions();   
        $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->setQuoteItemId(0)
                ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
                ->setProductId($itemValue->getProductId())
                ->setProductType($itemValue->getTypeId())
                ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
                ->setTotalQtyOrdered($itemValue->getRqty())
                ->setQtyOrdered($itemValue->getQty())
                ->setName($itemValue->getName())
                ->setSku($itemValue->getSku())
                ->setPrice($itemValue->getPrice())
                ->setBasePrice($itemValue->getPrice())
                ->setOriginalPrice($itemValue->getPrice())
                ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
                ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal)->setItemOptions($options);
        $subTotal += $rowTotal;
        $order->addItem($orderItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fetched the custom options from the quote item in the following way.

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');
            $options['additional_options'] = $helper->getCustomOptions($itemValue);
```

And then did set it on the order item using setProductOptions($options)

Cheers!

```
     $orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setQuoteItemId(0)
                    ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
                    ->setProductId($itemValue->getProductId())
                    ->setProductType($itemValue->getTypeId())
                    ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
                    ->setTotalQtyOrdered($itemValue->getRqty())
                    ->setQtyOrdered($itemValue->getQty())
                    ->setName($itemValue->getName())
                    ->setSku($itemValue->getSku())
                    ->setPrice($itemValue->getPrice())
                    ->setBasePrice($itemValue->getPrice())
                    ->setOriginalPrice($itemValue->getPrice())
                    ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)                        ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal)->setProductOptions($options);
```